# Скрипт баш Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

Tags: bash

Код

```
main() {
    extern wakeup();
    signal(SIGNALARM, wakeup);
    while (1); {
        alarm(5);
        pause();
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
./script.sh: 3: ./script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

Comment: А почему этот код так сильно смахивает на C, кто для bash делал реализацию функций signal, alarm, pause. и что такое extern. Причем тут вообще bash ???

Comment: А `;` в строке `while (1); {` - это нормально?

Comment: @Regent `while (1); do done` - это нормально

Comment: Но здесь какая-то адская смесь bash и C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
#!/bin/bash
main() {
extern wakeup\(\);
signal\(SIGNALARM, wakeup\);
while [ 1 ]; do
alarm\(5\);
pause\(\);
done
}
main
```

только у меня возникают ошибки на команды которых нет у меня в системе (Debian 8) но могут быть у вас: **pause** (может заменить на **sleep** ?), **extern**, **signal** и **alarm**. других идей нет.